# How to add additional map markers to Google Maps that are embedded on a website without using the API?  Or is it impossible?

Tags: html, google-maps, embed

Suppose I have 2 office locations which I want to use for my contact page.  And I want to have an embedded Google Map that shows both of those locations.  In Google Maps itself, I'm able to display both map markers.  However, the embed HTML code only uses the first address entered.

Question 1: Is it possible to change the HTML embed code that Google provides to display a map marker for the second location?

Question 2 (only if answer to above is "yes"): How?

Here is some sample embed code Google gives:

```
<iframe width="920" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.ca/maps?hl=en&amp;client=safari&amp;q=33+Victoria+St.,+Toronto,+ON+M5C+3A1&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=33+Victoria+St,+Toronto,+Ontario+M5C+3A1&amp;gl=ca&amp;t=m&amp;ll=43.536603,-79.796448&amp;spn=0.696882,2.526855&amp;z=9&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.ca/maps?hl=en&amp;client=safari&amp;q=33+Victoria+St.,+Toronto,+ON+M5C+3A1&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=33+Victoria+St,+Toronto,+Ontario+M5C+3A1&amp;gl=ca&amp;t=m&amp;ll=43.536603,-79.796448&amp;spn=0.696882,2.526855&amp;z=9&amp;iwloc=A&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
```

Comment: Well you could show two different maps with each of their location and information so the client knows there are two different locations and the different contact information for each.

Comment: Yes, this was my fall back plan, but ideally want to have it on a single map.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can achieve this another way, by using `My Places`. Here are the steps to achieve this:

1. In Google Maps, notice the `My Places` Button beside `Get Directions` - click on that.
2. Click on `Create a Map` in the Left Panel
3. Specify a Title and Description (something about your offices maybe), then hit Save.
4. Now search for your two locations as you would in the search bar.
5. Click on `Save to map` in the bottom of the result listing on the left panel, and specify the map you want to save it to (should be the title you set earlier).
6. Do that for both locations, then use the Embed tool like you would normally to embed your map.

Comment: Yes, this works, but you need to sign in to Google to create the My Place custom map.  And afterwards, when the map is embedded onto the website, if a user clicks on a map marker, the info bubble that pops up contains a link to the My Places of the creator of that map (and the creator's name shows).  Is there a way to keep it private?

Comment: hey, i'm not able to recreate your issue here ( http://jsfiddle.net/svigna/AFWge/ )..the only time the "My Places" shows is in the bottom where it asks `View random in a larger map`.

Comment: When I click on `View random in a larger map` it takes me to the map you created, and it says "Created on Jun 20 by  ".  Did you have to sign in to create this map?  When I tried, I had to sign in. Or what did you do to make it anonymous?

Comment: Hey, I did have to sign in to create the map. But I did not do any settings to make it anonymous, my map is actually public - so unfortunately I can't seem to recreate your issue. Try doing this: click on `My Places`, find your map in the left panel and click on that, then click on the embed tool and use the iframe provided there. If the problem still persists send me a link to your site, so I can have a look at what's going on.

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure about the answer to your question, but the Google API is pretty convenient and relatively easy to learn.

Creating a marker really only needs 3 lines, new marker, position of marker, and the map you are using. Creating a map with multiple markers is relatively short too in JS. Here is a sample.

```
function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
        myOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: map.getCenter(),
        map: map,
    });
    var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(35, 96),
        map: map,
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Using the API will also allow you to further add more features to your map if needed in the future. Eventually, you may want to have the markers display their location and perhaps even get directions to one of the markers. And Google has already written all this code that is available to anyone.

Here is a little more advanced example using the fusion tables API, but there are a lot of cool features that you can use besides just markers.
https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/infowindow_driving_directions

Comment: Thanks, I will try this, but can't make this accepted as it does not specifically answer the question about "without API".

Comment: I know. As I said earlier, the API is easy to learn and using the API will allow you to easily add more code and features in the event that you would ever want to further progress your map. By not using the API now, you might have to rewrite all your code eventually if and when you want more features for your map.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving your office locations to Google My Maps and then providing the link address of the map in the href of the iframe