# How to add multiple markers in embedded Google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-embed

I want to put multiple markers in my embedded map. I'm using iframe to embed the map. for 1 origin and 1 destination, it is working perfectly, but my requirement is to show multiple destinations with markers in the embedded map. I searched a lot but They say that you can't add multiple markers in an embedded map. Is it true? if not then please help me out here.Here is the 1 line code which I'm using to display the origin and destination.Thanks in advance

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?key=API_KEY&origin=Mumbai&destination=Nagpur&avoid=tolls|highways">
```

It is working perfectly but I want to add multiple destinations along with "Nagpur".

working example using waypoints

```
  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=mumbai&destination=pune&waypoints=raigad|nashik
```

Comment: Would you be better using a [static map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/), which can have multiple markers?  Or maybe just using the [Javascript Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/), writing your own javascript to load a map and as many markers as you like?

Comment: yah I have used a static-map and we can put multiple markers easily on that but the requirement was to put markers on embedded map, if it doesn't work then finally  I have to use static map only.

Comment: I just realised you're doing directions. I assume you mean markers at various spots on the route between Mumbai and Nagpur.  Can't you just use the `waypoints` parameter to specify them?

Comment: Thanks duncan for suggesting waypoints, Its really helpful , but I was searching that how I can pass "waypoints" in my above URL and get map with markers directly instead of getting JSON data.you got any idea?

Comment: Can you create a working example that I can test on JSFiddle?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, here is the working example using waypoints I have given it in my question itself.

Comment: Yes, but that's not using the /embed/ URL.  You should be able to do something like `<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?key=API_KEY&origin=Mumbai&destination=Nagpur&avoid=tolls|highways&waypoints=raigad|nashik">`

Comment: no , I dont have working example of waypoints with directions, thats what i m searching for, in working URL if i put waypoints, it doesnt give anything and the 2nd URL i gave u, if u copy paste that in the browser , it gives JSON

Comment: according to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#directions_mode) the waypoints parameter should work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126396/how-to-add-additional-map-markers-to-google-maps-that-are-embedded-on-a-website

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried signin in [google.com/maps](https://www.google.com/maps) with your Google accout and navigate to the "More" menu → Your places → maps → create new map?

You’ll be able to add your own markers and embed the map with all the features you need in the iframe.
The only drawback is that themarkers will be "static" in this case (but not the map).